# ImageField django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a problem with the image uploading from form (when i upload image from admin panel it works). Image just dont uploading, without any feedback and log. Help me pls

My view.py:

```
    def class_article_create(request, URLcodenumber):
        print(URLcodenumber)
    
        if request.method == 'POST':
            model = Article()
            form = ArticleForm(
                request.POST,
                instance=model
            )
    
            print(request.method)
    
            new_article = form.save(commit=False)
            new_article.codenumber = Classes.objects.filter(
                codenumber=URLcodenumber
            )[0]
            new_article.pub_date = date.today()
    
            print(new_article.id)
    
            if form.is_valid():
                new_article.save()
    
                return HttpResponseRedirect(f'/class/{URLcodenumber}')
    
        return render(
            request,
            'blogpage\\create_article.html',
    
            {
                'clsName': f'Параллель {URLcodenumber}',
                'codenumber': URLcodenumber,
                'form': ArticleForm()
            }
        )
```

My models.py:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(
        primary_key=True,
        default=uuid.uuid4,
        editable=False
    )
    headline = models.CharField(
        max_length=50,
        default='Нет заголовка'
    )
    text = models.TextField(
        max_length=600,
    )
    image = models.ImageField(
        upload_to='images/',
        blank=True
    )
    pub_date = models.DateField()
    codenumber = models.ForeignKey(
        'Classes',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
```

create_article.html

```
{% extends "blogpage\layout\base.html" %}
{% load static %}

{% block title %}
Добавление ответа
{% endblock title %}

{% block nav %}
<div class="classname-div">
    <p class="cls-name" align="center">{{clsName}}</p>
</div>

<a href='{% url "classpage_articles_preview" URLcodenumber=codenumber %}'>
    <button class="btn-to-page">Перейти к ответам</button>
</a>
{% endblock nav %}

{% block content %}
<form method="post" class="model-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}

    {{form.headline}}
    {{form.text}}
    {{form.image}}

    <button class="model-form-submit" type="submit">
        Добавить
    </button>
</form>
{% endblock content %}
```

early, there wasnt the *enctype="multipart/form-data"*, and the problem was same

media root and url in settings.py:

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')
```

urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.urls import re_path

from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

from help_page.helppage_views import help_page
from start_page import startpage_views
from help_page import helppage_views
from class_page import classpage_views


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path(
        '',
        startpage_views.start_page,
        name='startpage'
    ),

    path(
        'help/<numpage>/',
        helppage_views.help_page,
        name='helppage'
    ),

    path(
        'class/<URLcodenumber>/',
        classpage_views.class_article_preview,
        name='classpage_articles_preview'
    ),

    path(
        'create/<URLcodenumber>',
        classpage_views.class_article_create,
        name='classpage_articles_create'
    ),

    path(
        'view/<URLcodenumber>/<uuid:uuid>',
        classpage_views.class_article_view,
        name='classpage_article_view'
    ),

    path(
        'createclass',
        classpage_views.create_class,
        name='create_class'
    )
] + static(
    settings.MEDIA_URL,
    document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT
)
```

**proj_dir => media => images** is directory for the images

Thanks for any help! :)

Comment: You aren't showing what `ArticleForm` looks like. Also, you'd have an easier time using a `FormView`, or even a `CreateView`...

Comment: @AKX , sorry, i've forgot about form. That is `class ArticleForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = [
            'headline',
            'text',
            'image'
        ]

        labels = {
            'headline': 'Заголовок',
            'text': 'Ответ'
            # 'pub_date': 'Дата публикации'
        }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass both `request.POST` and `request.FILES` to the form:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404


def class_article_create(request, URLcodenumber):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        code_number = get_object_or_404(Classes, codenumber=URLcodenumber)
        form = ArticleForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.codenumber = code_number
            form.instance.pub_date = date.today()
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(f'/class/{URLcodenumber}')
    else:
        form = ArticleForm()
    return render(
        request,
        'blogpage/create_article.html',
        {
            'clsName': f'Параллель {URLcodenumber}',
            'codenumber': URLcodenumber,
            'form': form,
        },
    )
```

---

> **Note**: Django's [**`DateTimeField`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateTimeField)
> has a [**`auto_now_add=…`** parameter <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateTimeField.auto_now_add)
> to work with timestamps. This will automatically assign the current datetime
> when creating the object, and mark it as non-editable (`editable=False`), such
> that it does not appear in `ModelForm`s by default.